# How to add custom table style for table block in gutenberg editor

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, block-editor, editor

[image]

As per the image, I would like to add extra style for the table block.

Answer (score 3):

The [`register_block_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_block_style/) function is what you'll want.

The basic implementation is

```
register_block_style(
    'core/table',
    array(
        'name'  => 'my-table-style',
        'label' => 'My Table Style',
    )
);
```

When you select the style, it will add the `is-style-my-table-style` class to the block, which you can style using your `style.css` or other stylesheet.

There are two other implementations, where you can declare an inline style or a whole stylesheet for that specific style. You can find more details in the documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#register_block_style